# Put USB to PC Front Panel

Tags: usb, audio, motherboard, case, case-mods

I am going to DIY my PC case. But this problem happens to stock cases also.

For example, I use the [Gigabyte GA-Z97X-UD5H-BK](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5378#sp) motherboard. It has 2x USB 3.0 and 4x USB 2.0 ports through the internal USB header. If my PC case has less than (2+4) USB ports on the front, the capability of the motherboard is not utilised.

One solution is to add a 5.25" Drive Bay with USB ports. I would need (at least) 2x USB 3.0, 4x USB 2.0, Audio In, and Audio Out ports. It is not easy to find a product that fits. Are there any recommendations from high quality brand?

More importantly, I would like a more customise approach. Can I buy some dangling USB ports (as well as audio in/out ports) and fit them into the cut holes of my PC case? What exactly the terms of those products that I should search for?

Comment: Yes the case might provide less than 4 USB2+2 USB3, but you only need a usb front panel to fill what's missing from the case. i.e., if your case can do 2 usb 2+2 usb3, you'll only need 2x USB 2.0 for the front panel then.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will build my case from scratch. So i have zero USB ports to start from.

Comment: I see. Try searching "USB Header Cable", "USB 3.0 Header Cable" and "hd audio panel" on ebay..

Comment: Bingo! Thank you! These are the search terms!